# How to display multiple max columns from the max ID

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have the following query in SQL Server:

```
select 
    Max(STO.LeaveID) as LeaveID, 
    LR.EmployeeName, 
    STO.DateOff, 
    STO.TimeBegin, 
    STO.TimeEnd, 
    STO.PayPeriodEnd, 
    STO.TodayHoursOff, 
    STO.LeaveCode 
from 
    dbo.tblSeperateTimeOff STO
inner join 
    dbo.tblLeaveRequest LR on STO.LeaveID=LR.ID
inner join 
    dbo.tblLeaveApproval LA on STO.LeaveID = LA.LeaveID
where 
    LA.ApprovalDepartment like'%Finance%' 
    and EmployeeName like '%polland%' 
    and LA.IsApprove=1 
    and LA.IsFinalApprove=1 
group by 
    LR.EmployeeName, 
    STO.DateOff, 
    STO.TimeBegin, 
    STO.TimeEnd, 
    STO.PayPeriodEnd, 
    STO.TodayHoursOff, 
    STO.LeaveCode 
order by 
    EmployeeName
```

The result displayed:

```
LeaveID EmployeeName    DateOff     TimeBegin   TimeEnd     PayPeriod   Hours   LeaveCode
88      Polland, Sean   2014-09-08  08:30AM     11:00AM     2014-09-13  2.5     P (Personal Leave Scheduled*)
112     Polland, Sean   2014-09-24                          2014-09-27  8       P (Personal Leave Scheduled*)
121     Polland, Sean   2014-09-25                          2014-09-27  8       P (Personal Leave Scheduled*)
121     Polland, Sean   2014-09-26                          2014-09-27  8       P (Personal Leave Scheduled*)
```

I would like to get rid of the row with the LeaveID 112 and keep the 88 and the two 121's LeaveID. The reason for this is that I want it to have the same PayPeriod only from the max Leave ID. How would I format the query to make this happen? Thanks.

Comment: If you know the leave ID you want to eliminate can you not just add an additional condition and `LEAVEID NOT IN(112)`

Comment: You really should look at normalizing your data. You are storing the EmployeeName as a formatted value in every row. Also you are storing the text for LeaveCode. Both of those should be foreign keys to another table. Same thing with ApprovalDepartment.

Comment: DJ Kraze: I am using as an example, so I am declaring the EmployeeName in this scenario. In reality, there would be 100s of row with only where clause for ApprovalDepartment, IsApprove and IsFinalApprove. Another Employee could request the dates on the same payperiod but the LeaveID are similar to this situation. I just don't want the LeaveID 112 to be in there for this example without having to use a static condition like you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could do this.

```
create table #Something
(
    LeaveID int
    , EmployeeName varchar(25)
    , DateOff date
    , TimeBegin time
    , TimeEnd time
    , PayPeriod date
    , Hours numeric(9,2)
    , LeaveCode varchar(50)
)

insert #Something
select 88, 'Polland, Sean', '2014-09-08', '08:30AM', '11:00AM', '2014-09-13', 2.5, 'P (Personal Leave Scheduled*)' union all
select 112, 'Polland, Sean', '2014-09-24', null, null, '2014-09-27', 8, 'P (Personal Leave Scheduled*)' union all
select 121, 'Polland, Sean', '2014-09-25', null, null, '2014-09-27', 8, 'P (Personal Leave Scheduled*)' union all
select 121, 'Polland, Sean', '2014-09-26', null, null, '2014-09-27', 8, 'P (Personal Leave Scheduled*)';

with SortedResults as
(
    select *
     , DENSE_RANK() over(partition by PayPeriod order by LeaveID desc) as GroupDepth
    from #Something
)

select *
from SortedResults
where GroupDepth = 1

drop table #Something
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery to filter for max values for every id. Try adding this to your inner joins:

```
inner join 
  (
    select max(LeaveID) maxleaveid , PayPeriodEnd
    from tblSeperateTimeOff
    group by PayPeriodEnd
  ) m on sto.leaveid = m.maxleaveid and sto.PayPeriodEnd = m.PayPeriodEnd
```

I think this is what you need:

```
select 
    Max(STO.LeaveID) as LeaveID, 
    LR.EmployeeName, 
    STO.DateOff, 
    STO.TimeBegin, 
    STO.TimeEnd, 
    STO.PayPeriodEnd, 
    STO.TodayHoursOff, 
    STO.LeaveCode 
from dbo.tblSeperateTimeOff STO
inner join dbo.tblLeaveRequest LR on STO.LeaveID=LR.ID
inner join dbo.tblLeaveApproval LA on STO.LeaveID = LA.LeaveID
inner join 
  (
    select max(LeaveID) maxleaveid , PayPeriodEnd
    from tblSeperateTimeOff
    group by PayPeriodEnd
  ) m on sto.leaveid = m.maxleaveid and sto.PayPeriodEnd = m.PayPeriodEnd
where 
    LA.ApprovalDepartment like'%Finance%' 
    and EmployeeName like '%polland%' 
    and LA.IsApprove=1 
    and LA.IsFinalApprove=1 
group by 
    LR.EmployeeName, 
    STO.DateOff, 
    STO.TimeBegin, 
    STO.TimeEnd, 
    STO.PayPeriodEnd, 
    STO.TodayHoursOff, 
    STO.LeaveCode 
order by EmployeeName
```

Comment: Do you mean on both inner joins that I have? How would you format it?

Comment: @JonL I meant you should treat it like the other joins and just put the code fragment after the other joins

Comment: I have added that inner join block after the other two inner joins and before the where clause at the end and it still return the row with LeaveID 112 in it.

Comment: @JonL Oh, I think my brain took an early weekend leave... I was aggregating and grouping on the wrong attribute. It should by max(LeaveID) of course. I've updated the answer with a query that should be correct.

Comment: That is a good try jpw. The dateoff was group by to get different dates for the employees on the particular period. Your new query took off the group by and also the Max(STO.LeaveID) left me with 2 rows of LeaveID 112 instead of getting rid of it. Those two rows of LeaveID 112 is within the same payperiod and I do not need it.

Comment: @JonL I hope your comment referred to the previous version, not the last that I just added? Check this SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d759f/1

Comment: Yeah, It was. I just ran a query on your new updated query again and it returns 0 row now. I am taking a look to see why at this moment...

Comment: The new innerjoin that you wrote with the "select max(LeaveID) maxleaveid, payperiodend...." causing it to return 0 row.

Comment: @JonL Did you look at the fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d759f/1 ? I tried to reverse engineer your tables and data but maybe I made some mistake? I believe the query should be correct, but without proper data to test with it's kind of hard to tell what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to run a subquery to select the max `LeaveID` for each `PayPeriod` and `EmployeeName`, then `inner join` against that to filter out the other leaves.